# Performance of Conditional Inference regression Trees updating the influence function at each node

Tags: r, cart, rpart, party

My goal is to compare the performance of $2$ models of trees using the Conditional Inference tree framework described in (ctree: Conditional Inference Trees), I am following the Partykit 2018.

Dataset is formed by ($17520$ observations):

2 numeric (continuous) variable outputs

$15$ variable inputs ($11$ numeric (continuous), $4$ categorical).

The $2$ models of trees I am trying to build are:

1) Not defining $h$.

2) Defining an $h$, so that, $ytrafo=h$ (in order to evaluate the influence function at each inner node).

For the first scenario (Not defining $h$), these are the arguments that I have set up:

```
tm1 <- ctree(Ya + Yb ~ ., data = df12, control = 
ctree_control(teststat = "quadratic", testtype = "Bonferroni", alpha 
= 0.05, minsplit = 20L, minbucket = 7L, mtry = p/3, saveinfo = FALSE, 
update = FALSE))
```

For the second case $(ytrafo=h$), the arguments are as follow:

```
h <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights, offset, estfun = TRUE, 
object = FALSE, cluster = NULL) {
weights <- rep(1, NROW(y))

s <- id_trafo(y[weights > 0,,drop = FALSE])

r <- rep(c(0,0), length(weights))

r[weights > 0] <- s

list(estfun = matrix(as.double(r), ncol = 2), converged = TRUE, 
unweighted = TRUE)
}

tm2 <- ctree(Ya + Yb ~ ., data = df12, control = 
ctree_control(teststat = "quadratic", testtype = "Bonferroni", alpha 
= 0.05, minsplit = 20L, minbucket = 7L, mtry = p/3, saveinfo = FALSE, 
update = TRUE), ytrafo = h)
```

Both models run perfectly with no errors, however, I am not sure if in the case where I define $h$ I am missing an argument or even if the definition is correct.

Questions:

1) Is the influence function $h$ defined correctly? Am I missing something?

2) How to perform the accuracy of each model using the OOB observations?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the intended difference between `h` and the default `ytrafo` used by `ctree()`? How is `id_trafo()` defined? If it is conceptually the same transformation and just computed differently, then the two trees should be the same...

Comment: I thought that when we don't define h and make it equal to ytrafo, the id_trafo is:  "Note that this transformation
is only performed once for the root node and does not take weights
into account (which means, the forest bootstrap or subsetting is ignored, which is almost certainly not a good idea)." Hence, my goal was to define h so that the identity transformation is performed at each inner node (changing the argument update = TRUE).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you want to update the identity transformation locally in each node. This is the transformation that surely needs no updating because the identity does not change. Updating would be useful in situations where you compute something, e.g., residuals or scores from a local model.